# CMS built with PHP/SQL : My post content is all in one paragrah with no space, how do I fix this?

Tags: php, sql, content-management-system

This is my problem.

I am currently creating a blog entirely made up of PHP and SQL.

I have content that I want to display in each post, which is logged in my database.

So far, that's not a problem, as I am able to display each post's content easily. However there is just one problem: all the content is logged into one paragrah, so there is no space.

Normally, in every blog post you have multiple paragrahs and space right ? Well for me everything is in one paragrah, which makes things look ugly.

Here is my PHP:

```
     <?php

    $query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id = $the_post_id";
$select_posts = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_posts)){
          $post_id = $row['post_id'];
          $post_author = $row['post_author'];
          $post_title = $row['post_title'];
          $post_content = $row['post_content'];
          $post_image = $row['post_image'];
          $post_tags = $row['post_tags'];
          $post_date = $row['post_date'];

    ?>

    <article>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
          <img src='postImages/<?php echo $post_image; ?>' style='width: 100%; height: 500px'>
            <p><?php echo $post_content ?></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>

<?php } ?>
```

How do I fix this ?

All responses are appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You should use that function:

```
function nl2p($str) {
    $arr=explode("\n",$str);
    $out='';

    for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++) {
        if(strlen(trim($arr[$i]))>0)
            $out.='<p>'.trim($arr[$i]).'</p>';
    }
    return $out;
}
```

It replaces each \n(new line) to new paragraph and returns result. So place it somewhere in code then just invoke **echo nl2p($post_content);**

Function got from there: [How do I surround all text pieces with paragraph tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961217/how-do-i-surround-all-text-pieces-with-paragraph-tags)